# How do I plot a 3D surface on top of a 3D plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Consider, as an example, the Shannon entropy of probabilities defined over three possible outcomes:
$$H(p_1,p_2,p_3)\equiv -p_1\log p_1-p_2\log p_2-p_3\log p_3.$$
I want to study the behaviour of $H$ over the surface of points $0\le p_i\le1$ such that $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

An easy way to do this with `Plot3D` is leveraging `ColorFunction` as in the following:

```
entropy[list_] := -list*Log2@list // Total;
Plot3D[1 - x - y,
  {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= x + y <= 1, {x, y}],
  PlotRange -> All,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Temperature"][entropy@{x, y, z}/1.5]]
]
```

[image]

However, I would like to use an actual `Plot3D` to visualise this, by which I mean to have the actual 3D surface drawn *on top* of the plane. 
What is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to find a rigid transform to the xy plane, plot the function, and transform back.

```
tf = RootApproximant /@ 
  Chop[FindGeometricTransform[
    IdentityMatrix[3], 
    {{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[3/2], 0}}
  ][[2]]]
```

[image]

```
plot3d = Plot3D[
  0.5entropy[tf[{x, y, 0}]], 
  {x, y} ∈ Triangle[{{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0}, {Sqrt[2]/2, Sqrt[3/2]}}], 
  ColorFunction -> "Temperature",
  Mesh -> None
];

plot3drot = plot3d /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> GraphicsComplex[tf[pts], rest];

Show[plane, plot3drot]
```

[image]